# copy pandas dataframe and series

Tags: python, pandas, reference, copy, series

If I reference a name to a list, I know that that last line of code changes both values in a and b:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
b[1] = 4
```

Hence (one of) the right way to do it is to use: `b = a[:]`. In this way, changing values of b will NOT affect values of a.

However, the same doesn't seem to be true for pandas series or dataframes:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({1: [2,3,4], 2: [3,4,5]})
b = a[:]
b.loc[2,2] = 10
```

The last line of code will change both b and a. 
Can someone explain to me why is there a difference here? Also, what is the right way to create a new series/dataframe without affecting the original series/dataframe then? Should I ALWAYS use `b = a.copy(deep=True)`?

Comment: `b = a.copy()`, you need a deep copy here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a[:]` creates a shallow copy. With a shallow copy, the underlying data and indices are borrowed from the original - for performance reasons, the underlying numpy array data is the *same*. That's why the `deep=True` switch is turned on by default when you use `a.copy()` - you don't have to worry about modifying the original, since the underlying data is also replicated. With `a[:]`, it is assumed you know what you're doing.

Comment: sorry i am still confused: why does a[:] "work" for numpy list not but for series/dataframes?

Comment: @ian_chan Because series/dataframes are complex objects that encapsulate a lot more than just arrays of data.